# How to close broken bus line?

Tags: cities-skylines

After a big reorganization and the complete demolishing of an industrial area, I ended up with a broken bus line with two loose ends.  How can I connect the ends to close it?  Usually these ends tie themselves up automatically, but this time it's just not happening, no matter where I drag the stops. Adding new stops creates new lines.

Please see the red line below:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Finally I found the cause of the problem:

There was a leftover stop in the demolished area.  Somehow this stop was stuck in the middle of the forest, *with no roads around*, and couldn't be interacted with.  I think it must be a bug in the game.

I built a road close to it (but not on it) then dragged the line to go on that road.  After this I was able to remove the stray stop and the line automatically connected up its lose ends.

I hope this will help others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly (once I actually read your post with thought and built the road and line *near but not on* the non-interactable stop). After a few seconds the old stop just disappeared and the line became connected.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did to. Now if only to figure out how to do it with Metros!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem a bunch of times and almost always ended up deleting the whole line and creating a new one. I just finaly found a solution.

The problem was the one Carl mentioned. "Ghost" stops at deleted stations.

The solution is to select the broken line, click on a stop on the right and then click through the stops until you reach the ghost stop. That window has a "delete stop" button, wich aktivates when pressing "alt". Delet the stop and the line will connect the stop bevor that one with the one after that one. Then drag the line on a new stop, if needed.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out another thing that could be causing it.  In my city I had changed the traffic routing such that you couldn't get from one stop to the other.  Once I fixed the traffic routing the bus line self-connected